# Does dwolla allow functionality for the merchant to disburse funds to customers?

Tags: dwolla

I am working on a startup in which the merchant has to disburse funds to customers periodically, from time to time. Think of this as customer loyalty program, cashback etc.

Does dwolla support the ability to transfer money from merchant to customer?
Technically it seems the same as from one bank account to another but just wanted to confirm if that is the case. (Is there a refund API that can help with this?)

Also, would something like this be against the terms of use ? Is there a possibility of running into compliance bottle necks?

Appreciate your help in this as this would help me choose dwolla as our payment processor.

Thanks and Best Regards,

Answer (score 3):

I'll let Michael chime as well but the generic answer is yes. You can do that. You'd simply make an outgoing payment from a bank (or dwolla balance) to the receivers e-mail or phone #.

Not against the terms at all. Let us know if you need any guidance during the process.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you're describing sounds completely legitimate to me. The only caveat I can see here, is the fact you'll have to store the merchant's PIN number in order to periodically send money from their account, without their direct involvement (or am I understanding this wrong?) - our ToS requires that you hash/encrypt said PIN in your DB.

Regarding a refund API - we don't have one yet. You'l have to simply use the send() method, and if you're so inclined, feel free to break the amount to $10 chunk to avoid any fees.

Bottom line: you should be good to go.